# Bioinformatics - "global name 'start' is not defined"?

Tags: python, bioinformatics

Design and write a program that could detect transmembrane domains called `TMscanner.py`. This program should call two other functions that you write: `getProteinRegion` should return a ten amino acid window (initially grabs amino acid 1-10, the next time 2-20, etc.) The `TMscanner` should also repeatedly call  a second function called `testForTM` which should calculate and return the decimal fraction of those ten amino acids which are nonpolar. The nonpolar amino acids are [A,V,L,I,P,M,F,W]

Example:

```
protein = 'AVLIPMFWGSTNQYDEKRH' #Only the first 9 are nonpolar
results = tmScanner(protein)
print "Results are", results
```

It should print out:

```
Results are [.8, .7, .6, .5, .4, .3, .2, .1, 0, 0]
```

--
    #Test code

```
def getProteinRegion(protein, start):
#return first 10 aa in protein
    return protein[start:start+10]

def testForTM(protein):
#return ratio of nonpolar aa from a sample of first 10; move them up one step and repeat
    nonpolar = 0
    for aa in getProteinRegion(protein, start):
        if aa in ['A', 'V', 'L', 'I', 'P', 'M', 'F', 'W']:
            nonpolar = nonpolar + 1.0
    return nonpolar / 10.0


def tmSCANNER(protein):
#while the tested in testForTM is less than 10, append testforTM function to results; print results
    results = []
    start = 0
    while start <= 10:
        results = results.append(testForTM(protein))
        return results
        start = start + 1

##TESTING

#print getProteinRegion('AVLIPMFWGSTCNQYDEKRH')
#print testForTM('AVLIPMFW')
print tmSCANNER('AVLIPMFWGSTCNQYDEKRH')
```

--

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TMscanner.py", line 29, in <module>
    print tmSCANNER('AVLIPMFWGSTCNQYDEKRH')
  File "TMscanner.py", line 21, in tmSCANNER
    results = results.append(testForTM(protein))
  File "TMscanner.py", line 10, in testForTM
    for aa in getProteinRegion(protein, start):
NameError: global name 'start' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `testForTM` doesn't take a `start` parameter, doesn't declare a local variable named `start`, and yet it calls `getProteinRegion(protein, start)`. So, Python assumes you must be using a global—but you don't have a global with that name either. So it raises an exception.

What you probably want is to add `start` as a parameter:

```
def testForTM(protein, start):
```

And then, in the calling code inside `tmSCANNER`, where you *do* have a local variable named `start`, that's probably the value you want to pass as the `start` argument:

```
results = results.append(testForTM(protein, start))
```